Convert GIS Raster to CSV and plot as points on the grid using Python
I'm trying to convert raster to CSV file with coordinates and plot them and encounter a problem.
I have a raster .tif file with some buildings in Denmark projected in EPSG:7416 CRS.
I read .tif file as follows:
import rioxarray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
import xarray
import rioxarray
import numpy as np
import rasterio

raster_reprojected = rioxarray.open_rasterio("denmark_buildings.tif").squeeze()

Then, I plot opened raster as follows:
fix, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 12), dpi=500)
raster_reprojected.plot.imshow(ax=ax, alpha=0.5, add_colorbar=False)

plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

min_longitude = 620561.9971020991
max_longitude = 621791.9681244957
min_latitude = 6108663.515810543
max_latitude = 6110367.123382721
# # Zoom in to the area of interest
# # Set the limits of x and y to the region you want to zoom into
ax.set_xlim([min_longitude, max_longitude])
ax.set_ylim([min_latitude, max_latitude])

I'm getting the following results, which look decent for me.

After that I am converting the .tif file into .xyz format using GDAL
# Convert using GDAL Translate Driver
# read .tif file
ds_buildings = gdal.Open("denmark_buildings.tif")
ds_buildings_xyz = gdal.Translate("denmark_buildings.xyz", ds_buildings)
ds_buildings_xyz = None

Then I'm saving it as CSV file as follows:
df_buildings = pd.read_csv("denmark_buildings.xyz", sep=' ', header=None)
df_buildings.columns = ['x', 'y', 'value']
# Save it as a CSV file
df_buildings.to_csv("denmark_buildings.csv", index=False)

After that I'm reading CSV as numpy array as follows:
## Read csv as numpy array
buildings_array = np.loadtxt("denmark_buildings.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
# Get X and Y coordinates as lists
x_buildings = buildings_array[:, 0]
y_buildings = buildings_array[:, 1]

And plotting it as scatter
# Create a figure and a set of subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 12), dpi=500)

# Plot the data
ax.scatter(x_buildings, y_buildings, s=0.01, c='red', label='Buildings')

min_longitude = 620561.9971020991
max_longitude = 621791.9681244957
min_latitude = 6108663.515810543
max_latitude = 6110367.123382721
# Zoom in to the area of interest
# Set the limits of x and y to the region you want to zoom into
ax.set_xlim([min_longitude, max_longitude])
ax.set_ylim([min_latitude, max_latitude])

# Show the plot
plt.show()

I would expect to see the dottes on scatter forming the form of buildings, but instead I am getting wired picture with red dots everywhere as follow

Can someone help me what I'm doing wrong here? Why don't I see red buildings in dots on the picture? Here is the "denmark_buildings.tif" file which I use as input.

why are you doing this? That data makes much more sense as a raster, if you just need building outlines there are better vector datasets available/

@IanTurton Because I need buildings as grid points, coordinates, and not as an area.
